# Trouble with gulp and browser sync

Tags: html, css, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I am currently working on a starter project for future use that uses gulp and browser-sync to auto load new changes in the browser. I have it working for scss to css and for auto reloading html changes. The issue is that when it auto reloads html changes scss changes are all removed. For example, if I set changed the background color and save, the changes show up. Then I go to index.html and make a change and that shows up as well but removes the changes from the styles.scss file.

I have tried doing this with tasks as well as with functions. Neither has worked.

EDIT: I have gotten it to work by putting the index.html file in the main (./) directory. But I shouldn't have to do that to get it to work. Not sure why it doesn't work with index in the src folder

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');


// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
function style(){
    return gulp.src('./src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './src'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', style);
    gulp.watch('./src/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>This is a basic starter file!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

There are no error messages when I run this. The only issue is that saving the .html file removes the styles.scss changes.

Comment: Try removing the `./` from your `gulp.watch()` and see what happens.

Comment: That did not work

Comment: So, is your CSS file getting overwritten when you save your index.html?

Comment: That is correct. It reverts to having no css applied.

Comment: did you figure it out yet? i'm also stuck on this

Comment: here's my gulp file, works well, but had to replace stream with reload because stream didn't work https://pastebin.com/2Ya9X4Lr